# Material UI KeyboardDatePicker > allow users to type 1 digit for 1 digit months and days

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-formatting

I want to allow users to type: 1/1/2021 instead of 01/01/2021.
But, also still allow them to type 12/1/2021. (if the month is 12 months)

This is the docs: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker

If you set format to `M/d/yyyy` it works for 1/1/2021 but will not work for 12/1/2021.

Doesn't appear you can specify multiple formats.

This component seems to support this out of the box but would like to
https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-date-format